# Nodejs include Models

Tags: node.js, model

Im having problems to make my server.js use my models.

I do have other models with same structure, like for example:

```
    var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
```

but they works fine.. somehow.

But if If i try to use:

```
var Crime = mongoose.model('Crime');
```

i get:

```
         throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Crime".
```

if i switch to:

```
var Crime = require('./models/Crime');
```

or

```
var Crime = require('./models/Crime.js');
```

i get the response:

```
Cannot find module './models/Crime'
```

Crime model code:

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');



var CrimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  time: String,
  salt: String
});

CrimeSchema.methods.performCrime = function(pass) {

    /*var deferred = $q.defer();


    deferred.notify('loading....');
     deferred.reject('Greeting is not allowed.');


  return deferred.promise;
  */

  return 22;
};


mongoose.model('Crime', CrimeSchema);
```

EDIT

example of working model:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
```

and post.js model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.upvotes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

PostSchema.methods.downvote = function (cb) {
  this.upvotes -= 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to export the module at the end.

```
var Crime = mongoose.model('Crime', CrimeSchema);    
module.exports = Crime;
```

Comment: END of file or where o

Comment: End of file yes. Replace this code `mongoose.model('Crime', CrimeSchema);` by my answer

Comment: Which error ? `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Crime".` or `Cannot find module './models/Crime'`

Comment: if i do var Crime = mongoose.model('Crime'); , then it would with your answer be number one schema.

Comment: mo matter what i do there, i get the same errors as above with your code.

Comment: in your server.js you should have `var Crime = require('./models/crime');`. Assuming that your server.js and your models folder are inside the same folder

Comment: yeah @john , but it still dosent work. Btw how come my other models do work?

Comment: Are you sure than you calling your crime model `var Crime = mongoose.model('Crime');`  before the mongoose.connect ?